# Extract time from ISO8601 string

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdate, iso8601

I have an ISO8601 string

```
2013-05-11 05:54:07.589698
```

Is there anyway to extract just the time from this without string manipulation?

Comment: Google `NSDateFormatter`.

Comment: Furthermore, this is not an ISO8601 string

Comment: thanks h2c03! Sometimes I just need to know where to look. pardon the ignorance and thanks for the help. And sorry this isn't a ISO8601 formatted timestamp string?

Comment: ok so from what I've read, there's no way to turn this 2013-05-11 05:54:07.589698 into this 05:54:07 without manipulating the string first two separate the two. Is this correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many answers for similar questions, just posting this answer incase you haven't found it yet

```
NSString *inputString = @"2013-05-11 05:54:07.589698";

NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [NSDateFormatter new];
[dateFormatter setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneWithAbbreviation:@"UTC"]];
[dateFormatter setLocale:[[NSLocale alloc]initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_US_POSIX"]];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSSSSS"];

NSDate *date = [dateFormatter dateFromString:inputString];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"HH:mm:ss"];
NSString *timeString = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:date];

NSLog(@"%@",timeString);
```

Comment: god I love you...so very very much.  THANK YOU!